# Fancyhdr not working on every page

Tags: table-of-contents, fancyhdr

I'm trying to find our,why my fancyhdr is not working on every page. Could someone pls give me a hint.

merci in advance A

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
 openany,%removes blank pages between chapters
11pt,% The default document font size, options: 11pt
]{book}% The class file specifying the document structure
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%zeigt umlaute richtig an
\usepackage[default,light,bold]{sourceserifpro}%Source Serif Pro Light
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%erlaubt Umlaute
\usepackage[margin=1in,headsep=2in]{geometry}% provides an interface to page dimensions like setting margins
\usepackage{amsmath}% these packages allow much of the mathematical formatting
\usepackage{amssymb}% these packages allow much of the mathematical formatting
\usepackage{hyphenat}%can dis­able all hy­phen­ation or en­able hy­phen­ation of non-al­pha­bet­ics or monospaced fonts
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%provides an easy way to place text on the top and/or bottom of every page
\usepackage[ngerman,british,USenglish]{babel} %lädt die deutsche Sprache
\usepackage{graphicx}% lets you determine how to import external graphics 
\usepackage{multicol}%de­fines a mul­ti­cols en­vi­ron­ment which type­sets text in mul­ti­ple columns
\usepackage{booktabs}%fancy tables
\usepackage{array}%ex­tends the op­tions for col­umn for­mats, and pro­vides "pro­grammable" for­mat spec­i­fi­ca­tions
\usepackage{xcolor}%pro­vides easy driver-in­de­pen­dent ac­cess to sev­eral kinds of color tints, shades, tones, and mixes of ar­bi­trary col­ors
\usepackage{caption}%allows to cus­tomise the cap­tions in float­ing en­vi­ron­ments like fig­ure and ta­ble
 \usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{setspace} % setting of linespacing
\usepackage{multirow}%provides a construction for table cells that span more than one row of the table
\usepackage{upquote}%mod­i­fies the be­haviour of ver­ba­tim*and \verb* to print in the “` and ' way”, fixes the " and '
\usepackage{vmargin}% provides macros for setting document margin
\usepackage{acronym}  %intoc = nomcl auch im toc anzeigen
\usepackage[automake, nopostdot]{glossaries}
 \makeglossaries


\setglossarystyle{listgroup}


\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
  name=latex,
 description={Is a mark up language specially suited for 
scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
        name=mathematics,
        description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}


\linespread{1.0} % sets the inter-line spacing in a document



\clearpage
\setlength{\headsep}{1pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}

\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\documentnumber~Rev.~\currentrevision}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}% LeftEven,RightOdd
\fancyfoot[LO,CE]{A.Rose}% LeftOdd, CenterEven
\fancyfoot[CO,RE]{\today} % CenterOdd,RightEven
}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}

\def \currentrevision{A}
\def \documentnumber{\bfseries Baselining-001}




\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace{1cm}
% \includegraphics[scale = 0.15]{enclogo.png}   \\[1.0cm] % energicos logo
 \vspace{2cm}

\line(1,0){400}\\[1mm]
\huge{\textbf{Baselining mittels Retrograder Ermittlung von Heizlasten über diskrete Betriebsstunden}}\\[3mm]

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
%\setcounter{page}{1}}

\newpage

\chapter*{List of Symbols}
\begin{doublespace}
\begin{longtable}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm} p{11cm}}\toprule
\textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Erläuterung} \\\midrule
${Q_{Tag}}$&  Warmwasserbedarf in kWh je Tag (Durchschnitt)\\
${Q_{Periode}}$ &  Anteil Base\\
$\beta$ &  Warmwasserbedarf in kWh je Jahr (historischer gemessener Wert)\\
${D_{Periode}}$ & Service Fee/ Dienstleistungsgebühr\\
${\dot{Q}}_{WW}$ &  Speicherwärmemenge\\
$z$ &  Spitzenlast  für  die Warmwasserbereitstellung (Leistung in Bedarfszeitraum)\\
$Q$ &  maximale Leistung des Wärmeerzeugers)\\
${z_{norm}}$ & Referenzzeitraum ist immer eine Stunde (${z_{norm}}$ = 1 h aka 60 min)\\
$z_{Auheiz}$ & Warmwasservorrangbetriebszeit \\
$Q$  & größte Wärmebedarf zur Warmwassererzeugung (nach Warmwasserprofil z.B. am Morgen mit 22 kWh)\\
${\dot{Q}}_{WW}$ &  Spitzenlast  für  die Warmwasserbereitstellung (Leistung in Bedarfszeitraum)\\
${\dot{Q}}_{WEA}$ &  maximale Leistung des Wärmeerzeugers)\\
$\frac{z}{z_{norm}}$ & Zeitraum Bedarfzeit für Spitzenbedarf Warmwasser zu 1 Stunde\\
${z_{norm}}$ & Referenzzeitraum ist immer eine Stunde (${z_{norm}}$ = 1 h aka 60 min)\\
$Q$ &  Speicherwärmemenge\\
${\dot{Q}}_{WW}$ &  Spitzenlast  für  die Warmwasserbereitstellung (Leistung in Bedarfszeitraum)\\
${\dot{Q}}_{WEA}$ &  maximale Leistung des Wärmeerzeugers)\\
$\frac{z}{z_{norm}}$ & Zeitraum Bedarfzeit für Spitzenbedarf Warmwasser zu 1 Stunde\\
${z_{norm}}$ & Referenzzeitraum ist immer eine Stunde (${z_{norm}}$ = 1 h aka 60 min)\\
$Q$ &  Speicherwärmemenge\\
${\dot{Q}}_{WW}$ &  Spitzenlast  für  die Warmwasserbereitstellung (Leistung in Bedarfszeitraum)\\
${\dot{Q}}_{WEA}$ &  maximale Leistung des Wärmeerzeugers)\\
$\frac{z}{z_{norm}}$ & Zeitraum Bedarfzeit für Spitzenbedarf Warmwasser zu 1 Stunde\\
${z_{norm}}$ & Referenzzeitraum ist immer eine Stunde (${z_{norm}}$ = 1 h aka 60 min)\\
${\dot{Q}}_{WW}$ &  Spitzenlast  für  die Warmwasserbereitstellung (Leistung in Bedarfszeitraum)\\
$\frac{z}{z_{norm}}$ & Zeitraum Bedarfzeit für Spitzenbedarf Warmwasser zu 1 Stunde\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{doublespace}
\captionof{table}{List of Symbols}\label{tbl:nicetablelesstable}


\chapter*{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\begin{acronym}[SEPSEP]%SEPSEP gibt den Absatz
\acro{z}[Z]{Zellen}
\acro{mh}[MH]{Maus}
\end{acronym}

\newpage
\listoffigures % Prints the list of figures

\newpage

\listoftables % Prints the list of tables

\newpage


\printglossaries

\newpage


\chapter{Prämissen des Modells}
\minitoc

\newpage
\section{Grundannahmen zum Modell diskrete Betriebsstunden}\label{modell-diskrete-betriebsstunden}


\begin{itemize}
\item
  hierbei wird immer auf die bisherigen gemessenen Verbrauchswerte
  abgestellt

\end{itemize}

The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable 
for documents that include \gls{maths}. 


\section{Prämissen/ Annahmen des Modells}\label{i.-pruxe4missen-annahmen-des-modells}
\subsection{Raumheizung}

  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    es wird angenommen, dass der Wärmeerzeuger auf die maximale Heizlast
    für das Gebäude ausgelegt ist, das heißt in der Stunde in der die
    \end{itemize}


\subsection{Prämissen Warmwasserbereitung}

  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    dabei wird davon ausgegangen, daß die Warmwasserbereitung in
  \end{itemize}

\newpage

    \begin{itemize}
    \item
      unterbricht während der Trinkwassererwärmung, d. h. während der
      Aufheizung des Warmwasserspeichers, die Raumbeheizung
   \end{itemize}

\subsection{ PrämissenHydraulischer Abgleich}

  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    das System ist hydraulisch abgeglichen
  \end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Make a *minimal* compilable example demonstrating your problem. And don't ask two question at once.

Comment: Welcome ! Please follow Ulrike Fischer's advice to provide a MWE. See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to see how to do it properly

Comment: Hi BambOo, thats a  minimal MWE, the entire thesis is 300 pages strong.../ dropped the second question :-)

Comment: How is that minimal? float, xfrac, multicol, soul etc has nothing to do with the headers/fancyhdr

Comment: well, i removed all the usepackages i thing can be safely removed without breaking it...

Comment: still not minimal, but have you checked https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116950/thispagestyleplain-has-no-effect and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267792/redefining-fancyhdr-for-plain-changes-non-chapter-pages-header-footer? `plain` is not used for all the pages, some are `empty`...

Comment: Hi Rmano, that is imho minimal, i need all the remaining parts to show the error, and no, the links are referrring to another problem

Comment: I bet 100 € that you don't need `\usepackage{eurosym}` to show a problem with the headers.

Comment: I am pretty sure keeping only one `itemize` won't make much of a difference either

Comment: Also, I just tested you snippet and i **cannot compile it !**

Comment: well, removed everything nonessential and tried to compile it, it compiles. but then you will see the fancyhdr doesnt show on page 4 an 10

Comment: @aerioeus then please update your question with this updated MWE

Comment: i just did, merci

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is straightforward: you have redefined the pagestyle `plain`, but `plain` is not used on most pages. For most pages the style used is `headings`, although the best thing to do is to define `myheadings` and set `\pagestyle{myheadings}`

```
\fancypagestyle{myheadings}{%
\fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  \addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}
  \fancyhead[RE,LO]{WHAT I WANT TO SEE}}

\pagestyle{myheadings}
```

You will probably want to put your footer stuff back in there too. I took it out, pedantically, because your complaint was about headings.

Now a MINIMAL example is not "anything it needs to make my document compile" but simply "anything I need to *reproduce this problem* using as few packages as possible". For future record, you can demonstrate your problem using only the code below. You could have got there, as I did, by removing packages and recompiling. I realise it's not always easy to guess what the issue is, but if you have more than a few packages you don't have an MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  \addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}
  \fancyhead[RE,LO]{WHAT I WANT TO SEE}}


\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Prämissen des Modells}

Header is correct on this page.

\newpage

\section{Grundannahmen zum Modell diskrete Betriebsstunden}

And wrong on this one.
\end{document}
```

(That's 73 words/262 characters, where you had 889/6852. And in fact one could get rid of both fontenc and inputenc by making one other change!)

Comment: +1 for the code golf aspect of your answer :) You could save some more characters by making the chapter and section titles shorter :)

Comment: Also `a4paper` and `11pt` are not necessary for the "minimal working answer" :)

Comment: Dear Paul, thank you very much. I will definitely reduce the characters to a min in the future, sorry I'm still a beginner, so I'm still getting used to the rules here. But as said, totally understand your point. as for the solution: it only works half for me. I used  your code and swapped it against mine but for the first pages (toc, List of figures etc.) no header is showing. Do you have any idea, why would that be? merci

Comment: Dear Paul, adding to my earlier commment, when I try to set the pagestyle after a \newpage and hence add \thispagestyle{myheadings} nothing happens. Do you have any idea, what the reason could be? merci in advance A

Comment: Don't set it there. Just set it all in the preamble (i.e. before `\begin{document}`, together with `plain`. LaTeX will automatically switch between them. You could just set `\pagestyle{plain}` I suppose with your code, but I'd rather do it differently.

Comment: I just duplicated the definition you created for the pagestyle(plain) and it worked. is that the proper appoach? at least I have now on all pages the header? :-)

Comment: So long as you are sure you don't want ever to have a different header and footer on the first page of a chapter, you are OK simply defining plain and setting the headings to it. IMO, generally, it looks better to leave chapter openings plain. But you are in charge and there's no technical reason that I know of to object to it.